# Longer query execution time Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two derived tables `system_type_a` and `system_type_b` which both use the table `system` along with `type_a` and `type_b` respectively. `type_a` has ~15k records and `type_b` has ~5k records. I am doing a left join on both tables with `system`. However `system_type_b` is taking much higher execution time as compared to `system_type_b`. I tried viewing the execution plan for both queries as suggested in a stack exchange response to a similar query however I am not able to make much sense of it.

Comment: what kind of an question is this ? a quick homework ?? system_type_b compared with same table

Comment: can you provide the execution plan

Comment: Post your code or it doesn't happen.

Comment: @Jonathan No, its not a 'homework question. I have just used generic table names.

Comment: @JChao Both queries uses intermediate views and the execution plan in xml format has 1580 lines.

Answer (score 0):

The selectivity of joins might force different execution plans.
Maybe the statistics are old or not updated.
Also you can check fragmentation of the bad performing table. Maybe it requires more physical reads than the other one.

Comment: The second table when used with a simple select query works fine. The table structure of both these tables are very similar but for a simple filter.